# What are the neurobiological mechanisms behind clumsiness

Tags: neuroscience, sensation

Some people are inherently clumsy (including your's truly).  Everything from frequently stubbing their toes to, as in my case 2 days ago, falling down a single step and managing to crack a rib and strain my back when I landing over the letterbox, are quite bizarre.

The question is, what are the neurobiological mechanisms behind clumsiness?  I would imagine that it is somehow connected to coordination (of which I have almost none) and perhaps depth perception - but I would like refereed articles to clarify the reasons.

Comment: don't lose sight of the fact that your clumsiness may originate in your consciousness, and not be based in the biology.  Do search, though

Comment: @NewAlexandria Yes, I am aware of those reasons, I am after the neurobiological mechanisms in this question.